# A variable width div within a variable width parent div

Tags: css, position

So I have a "parent" div with a width in % inside a container. (the container could have a different size depending on a screen..)
And inside that "parent" I have several elements, a buttons area with a width fixed (so in px) and an input which should take all the space remaining.

I use boostrap 2.3.2 and usually I was trying to play with row-fluid and span8,span2 but the space between the input and the buttons was not always very nice.

Is there a way to force the input to fill in all the available space ?

here is a jsfiddle with the current code

http://jsfiddle.net/wgesasmj/

**current css**

```
.container {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: beige;
    padding: 10px;
}
.parent {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is add your own css class and play with `width` :

```
.fillall{
    width:70%;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgesasmj/1/)

**Update**

Change your markup in accordance with bootstrap (*and let there css do rest of the work*).

```
<div class="container"> <!-- or <div class="container-fluid"> -->
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="pull-left span8" /> 
                <a class="buttons pull-right btn btn-primary span2">Add</a>
                <a class="buttons pull-right btn btn-danger span2">Del</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgesasmj/3/)

Comment: Yes I tried those. But if the container gets bigger likehttp://jsfiddle.net/wgesasmj/2/
Then I have some space left.